# Cron job is still running even my script is not available on my server

Tags: php, email, curl, amazon-ec2, cron

I have written a script to send an email while cron calling my script ( Every minute like */1 * * * * curl http://myserver.com/myurl.php ). I have executed the cron before 6 days and day before yesterday I removed my script and also removed my crontab through putty. And i have the file (http://myserver.com/myurl.php) with another one different script for now. Also i again ran the cron. But still i am getting large number of emails ( From first script ) even the file doesnot have the script to send an email.

I have tried lot of time to to remove the jobs through putty as below:

```
crontab -r
```

Please help me on this. I looking for the solution. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: have you checked all existing cron jobs? /etc/cron.d

Comment: @S.Gholizadeh . Yeah I have checked and removed the whole jobs of user. Now i resolved my problem. Thanks to you. :)